# Вывод БД SQLite во вторую активность при клике на CardView?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, recyclerview, cardview

Хочу сделать справочник для аквариумиста, в общем в табе "Аквариумные рыбы" есть RecyclerView c CardView при клике на CardView открывается вторая активность. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать БД что б при клике на CardView с БД по _id подтягивало контент которым БД будет заполнена.
Собственно код:

Фрагмент "Аквариумные рыбы"

```
public class AquaFish extends Fragment {

private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.aqua_fish1;

private View view;
private List<FishName> fishNames;
private RecyclerView rv;

public static AquaFish getInstance() {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    AquaFish aquaFish = new AquaFish();
    aquaFish.setArguments(args);
    return aquaFish;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);

    //Создание списка
    rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv);

    //set LayoutManager
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

    //Инициализация даты и адаптера
    initializeData();
    initializeAdapter();

    return view;
}

private void initializeData() {
    fishNames = new ArrayList<>();
    fishNames.add(new FishName("Апистограмма Рамирези", "Mikrogeophagus ramirezi", R.drawable.f000_1));
    fishNames.add(new FishName("Боливийская бабочка", "Mikrogeophagus altispinosus", R.drawable.f000_2));
    fishNames.add(new FishName("Апистограмма агассица", "Apistogramma agassizii", R.drawable.f000_3));
    fishNames.add(new FishName("Апистограмма какаду", "Apistogramma cacatuoides", R.drawable.f000_4));
}

private void initializeAdapter() {
    RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(fishNames);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

А вот RecyclerView адаптер + ВьюХолдер и переход на 2ую активность

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {

static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView fishName, fishAbout;
    ImageView fishPhoto;
    ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        fishName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        fishAbout = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fish_about);
        fishPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        this.itemClickListener.OnClick(v, getLayoutPosition());
    }
}

Context context;
List<FishName> fishNames;

public RVAdapter (List<FishName> fishNames) {
    this.fishNames = fishNames;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    context = viewGroup.getContext();
    return new PersonViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
    personViewHolder.fishName.setText(fishNames.get(i).name);
    personViewHolder.fishAbout.setText(fishNames.get(i).about);
    personViewHolder.fishPhoto.setImageResource(fishNames.get(i).photoId);

    personViewHolder.itemClickListener = (new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnClick(View v, int pos) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity2.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
            }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return fishNames.size();
}
```

}

Comment: Если вы работаете с БД, то все данные должны быть в БД и иметь связи, зачем этот ArrayList с рыбами. Создаете две таблицы - заголовки с _id  и подробности по рыбам, которые связаны через _id заголовка. При клике на айтем из адаптера получайте _id кликнутого айтема через интерфейс обратного вызова (у вас уже реализован) и вызываете другое  активити, через интент передаете этот _id. В другой активити по полученному _id делайте запрос в БД на выборку дополнительной информации по этому _id.

Comment: Понял Вас, большое спасибо за подсказку )

Comment: не сам ArrayList, а данные должны быть **вместо** листа в БД и связаны через ID с подробностями о рыбах